# Coinductive principles corresponding to the *_rect family of functions

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coinduction

Defining a new type `foo` gives me a recursion principle `foo_rect`, which elegantly abstracts over `fix`. Could a coinductive equivalent (abstracting over `cofix`) be defined by "flipping the arrows" somehow?

Comment: Giménez and Castéran [implement](http://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/RecTutorial.pdf) "Park's Principle" in Coq, essentially a mirror image of the usual induction schema. It is also [discussed](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Coinductive.html) in Adam Chlipala's *Certified Programming with Dependent Types*, and Catalin Hritcu [published](https://hritcu.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/learning-teaching-coinduction-with-coq/) problem sets on the subject ([1](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW6.v), [2](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW67.v)).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible due to the non-modular way that Coq checks the guardedness condition for cofixpoints. Fortunately, the [Paco library](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/paco/) solves this problem by doing exactly what you want as long as you phrase your definitions in a particular way.

There is a good tutorial for the Paco library here: http://plv.mpi-sws.org/paco/tutorial.html